# Getting Minecraft Pi off full screen so I can program with Python in a separate editor

Tags: pi-4, raspberry-pi-os, minecraft

I'm new to Raspberry Pi OS, I've installed VSCode (ARM version), and Minecraft Pi (from the terminal).
Now I need to be able to run the game in a smaller window (not full screen) so I can see my editor. Every tutorial I've run into recommends a second monitor, which seems silly since the game has unused black borders around it currently.

I suspect this version is running a full screen emulator or something. Is there a way to run it in tandem with the Desktop. I found some recommendations to adjust the resolution or disable fullScreen in the options file, but I'm pretty sure that only applies to the full Windows version of Minecraft.

There isn't a menubar so I can't minimize or close the application either.

Comment: Press Esc to show the 'Game menu' then press Alt + F11. Works on Pi3 not sure about Pi4.

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + F11 brings it back to an empty system terminal with a blinking cursor. Ctrl + Alt + F1 does the same terminal but I can type commands into it.

I think I may go with Minecraft Forge and code from the Raspberry Jam mod on a separate machine.

One last effort, how does one switch programs in Raspberry Pi OS?